# Roblox lua UserInputService not displaying anything? possibily outdated. TheDevKing tutorial

Tags: lua, roblox

```
UserInputService=game:GetService("UserInputService")

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, gameProcessedEvent)
    if input.KeyCode==Enum.KeyCode.A then
        print("U pressed A")
    end
end)
```

My code is above. Is anything wrong with it, because it doesn't display anything?

Putting local before userinputservice

Print out "U pressed A"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource: https://devforum.roblox.com/t/userinputservice-not-working/1278104/2

"UserInputService" is supposed to be used in local scripts, not in server scripts.
Try writing your script in a LocalScript inside of StarterPlayer->StarterPlayerScripts.

Comment: I did do that. reference:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4z1HVwe0sLE&t=419s

Comment: Then it should work. I tested it and it works. Maybe you should post a bit more details.

Comment: it doesn't work for me did u copy and paste mine?

Comment: Yes. I copy and paste your code and it works.

Comment: oof hmm idk then, thhx for helping anyways

Comment: i tried copy and pasting it again but for some reason it still don't work

Comment: Maybe your script is disabled?

Comment: it's not i just check that rn

Comment: after changing it from A to T it worked. starnge lol. but thx for helping out. really appreciate that

Comment: silly mistake it was actually cos i didnt press on the screen so nothing happened !